# How to send laravel notification to a custom email

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel application,
I send notifications to a user when he registers. I use the notify() on the model. But I have an issue, How do i send a notification to a custom email address? the same notification.

Here's what i have:

```
   `$admin = Admin::find(1);

    $admin->email = 'admin@site.com';

    $admin->notify((new NewUserRegistered($user))->delay($when));

    $user->notify((new UserRegistered($user))->delay($when));`
```

i get a user model instance, and customize the email to input the custom email... However, the email sends to the original mail on the model and ignores the edit.
How do i do this please?

Comment: show full registration code

Answer (score 5):

Here the code snippet you can use for sending the notification directly to an email address without creating the User or without having the User in the database.

```
Notification::route('mail', 'me@abdulrehman.pk')->notify(new InvoicePaid($invoice));
```

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, you can save the model before sending the message

```
$admin->email = 'admin@site.com';
$admin->save();
```

after that you can retrieve the email as it was